# Can't display 8MP camera frame in C# PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing, bitmap

I have C# app that downloads frames from a USB camera and displays them in a Picture Box.  Works great with ELP 5MP USB camera.
But PictureBox remains black for SPINEL 8MP USB camera.

I'm using Windows 10 Pro laptop and Visual Studio 2017 C#,
and Accord VideoCaptureDevice for USB camera frame capture (http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Video_DirectShow_VideoCaptureDevice.htm)

Frame 'newby' parameters from Spinel 8MP camera are:

```
H: 720
HR: 96
PHYS DIM: 1280 X 720
PixelFormat: 32bppArgb
VerRes: 96
W: 1280
1280 x 720
```

Frame 'newby' parameters from ELP 5MP camera are:

```
h: 480
hr: 96
phys dim: 640 x 480
PixelFormat: 32bppArgb
Size: 640 X 480
VERTRES: 96
W: 640
```

C# code that starts download of frame Bitmaps from a camera:

```
var videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice( videoDevices[0].MonikerString, pixelFormat_for_ExhaustiveTemplateMatching);
videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler( EVENT_camera_frame );
videoSource.Start();
```

C# frame event code:

```
private static void EVENT_camera_frame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs camera_frame_event)
{

Bitmap newby = new Bitmap(     camera_frame_event);

PictureBox_live_camera.Image = newby;
PictureBox_live_camera.BackgroundImage = newby;

       . . .  processing and Bitmap disposal . . .
}
```

Comment: set `BackgroundImageLayout` poperty of picturebox to `System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom` and set `PictureBox_live_camera.BackgroundImage = newby`. don't use `PictureBox_live_camera.Image` property. Maybe this works for you.

Comment: How are you constructing a `Bitmap` from an `EventArgs` object? There's no such overload...